# DropDownList anidados Jquery ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, dropdownlist

Realice el proceso mediante Web Method, me muestra los datos en la consola, pero no me los carga en el combo. 
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

El codigo de Jquery es el siguiente:

```
 $("#cboPais").change(function () {

    var params = new Object();
    params.pais = $("#cboPais").val();
    params = JSON.stringify(params);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "SociosRed.aspx/GetDepartamentosByPais",
        data: params,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function(LoadDepartamento){
            console.log(LoadDepartamento);},
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus + ": " + XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
        }
    });

});
```

La funcion es:

```
function LoadDepartamento(result) {

$("#cboDepartamento").html("");


$.each(result.d, function () {
    $("#cboDepartamento").append($("<option></option>").attr("value", this.Codigo).text(this.Nombre))

});}
```

Comment: como estas declarando las funciones para onchange, ?ejemplo:PaisSeleccionado

Comment: Acabo de actualizar mi pregunta, asi tengo mi metodo

Comment: AutoPostBack="true", true con minusculas y tambien salta la validacion agrega CausesValidation="false"

Comment: Aun no me carga los datos. Siempre carga el Pais pero no lo demás.

Comment: como se obtiene ListarDepartamento?

Comment: Acabo de agregar esa informacion

Comment: en page_load tienes esta condicion de inici?o   private void Page_Load(object source, EventArgs e) {
    if (!Page.IsPostBack) {//cargar lista de paises

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                IniciarLlenadoCombo();
                LlenarEstablecimiento();
                LlenarPais();
            }
        }

Comment: Lo tengo de esa manera.

Comment: ahora si lo estas llenando desde el servidor para que agregaste jquery o javascript, $("#cboDepartamento").val(data[23]);
$("#cboProvincia").val(data[23]);
$("#cboDistrito").val(data[24]);

Comment: por un momento comenta tu codigo en javascript y tambien elimina todos los <div class="col-md-3">, algunas veces dropdownlist no trabajan bien si estan  anidadas en divs y envian eventos al servidor.

Comment: El javascript es para poder jalar los datos de un cliente ya registrado y poder actualizarlo. Cuando llamo esos datos desde JS, me aparece el país que corresponde, pero no el departamento, ni provincia ni distrito.

Comment: Podrías poner el código del departamento(protected void) para poder ver por qué no te sale los valores.

Comment: Lo acabo de agregar

Comment: Haz puesto de nuevo país, puedes corregirlo y poner departamento

Comment: Ya actualice la informacion

Comment: demos un paso atras cuando cargas la pagina, no tienes algun error en el navegador, que dice la consola?

Comment: en la consola no aparece ningún error, incluso me aparecen los campos que requiero; es decir, si los llama desde la BD. Pero en el formulario solo se muestra el valor de País.

Comment: he puesto una imagen de como me muestra.

Answer (score 0):

Estas mezclando `javascript` con evento de `asp.net` eso no funciona junto. 
Debes usar una des estas alternativas

- Evento de asp.net, quizas junto al `UpdatePanel` para que no se actualice la pagina

  [Cascading DropDownList for Country/State/City in ASP.Net](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Cascading-DropDownList-for-CountryStateCity-in-ASPNet.aspx)
- Usas `javascript` con `jquery` para obtener el `json` que cargar en `<select>` del html usando `$.ajax` y `webMethod`

pero no deberias combinarlas, es para problemas.

Bueno en realidad podrias llegar a una cierta union, o sea renderizar el `<asp:DropDownlit ..>`, pero no usas sus eventos, sino que estos sean del lado del cliente.

Como se explica aqui

[AJAX Cascading DropDownList using jQuery in ASP.Net](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/AJAX-Cascading-DropDownList-using-jQuery-in-ASP.Net.aspx)

Al definir el combo asocia el `onchange`, pero es un evento del cliente

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlContinents" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true"
         onchange = "PopulateContinents();">
    <asp:ListItem Text = "Please select" Value = "0"></asp:ListItem>                
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Despues expone un `webmethod`

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static ArrayList PopulateCountries(int continentId)
{
    //codigo
}
```

el cual invoca con `$.ajax` al usar

```
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: pageUrl + '/PopulateCountries',
        data: '{continentId: ' + $('#<%=ddlContinents.ClientID%>').val() + '}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnCountriesPopulated,
        failure: function(response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    });
```

Otro articulo donde explico algo parecido

[[jQuery] DropDownList anidados (nested DropDownList)](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com/2010/04/jquery-dropdownlist-anidados-nested.html)

[Cascading DropDownLists With ASP.NET and jQuery](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=417)

Comment: Gracias, ahora voy a intentarlo de esa manera. Lo estaba intentando con el update panel, pero como lo estoy haciendo en un modal igual me recargaba la pagina al seleccionar el departamento. Eso no pasaría con el Web Method?

Comment: el updatepanel no reresca la pagina pero si el template y todo lo que este contenga, con $.ajax y webmthod esto no sucedera

Comment: Estoy haciendo el web method según su manual, pero me sale un error al definir el item["CodPais"]. No se puede aplicar una indizacion con [] a una expresion del tipo departamento.

Comment: que es item ? no se que codigo estas aplicando peor en principio no veo porque estas usando un array, o si es codigo del lado del servidor

Comment: Acabo de ponerlo en mi pregunta, me estoy guiando de su manual.

Comment: si usas un List<Departamento> no necesitas del AsEnumerable(), puede acceder directo usando propiedades item.Cod

Comment: Entiendo, y como sería mi select y mi return? Como tendría que definirlos?
 var query = from item in ListaDepartamento
                        where item.CodigoPais == pais
                        select item.Codigo , item.Nombre;

            return query.ToList<Departamento>();
Asi me sale un error

Comment: porque haces un ToList<Departamento>(), solo usa el ToList(), ademas para que defines un select casteando dos propiedades si vas a devolver la misma entidad, solo define `... select item`

Comment: Realice el proceso mediante el Web Method, le puse un console.log para ver si me lista los datos y verifiqué que si lo hace, pero no me lo muestra.

Comment: Modifique la pregunta para que pueda observar el codigo

Comment: revisa nuevamente el ejemplo porque estas declarando mal el `success`

Comment: al succes solo le agregue el console.log para saber si me llama el listado, y si lo llega a llamar, pero no lo carga en el combo.

Answer (score 0):

Si juegas con los eventos selected_item y la selección de autopostback=true de cada DDL, vas a poder anidar los DDL que quieras sin necesidad de cosas distintas a asp.net puro y duro.

Debes tener en cuenta que si van en cascada, es decir el DDL n+1 depende de la selección de n, deberá ir eso explícito en el evento del DDL n+1.